# React-Redux: Add custom third parameter to mapStateToProps - possibly connectAdvanced?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an application using React and Redux.

Several parts of my data model are potientially lazy, so a common pattern when reading data from the redux state is: Lookup if lazy data is already loaded, if not, dispatch a ReduxThunk-action that fetches the data.

To be able to trigger this process within mapStateToProps I want to implement an own connect function that passes a resolve function as third parameter to mapStateToProps. This resolve function should have access to dispatch, so I could trigger the ReduxThunk-action loading of the lazy data. My mapStateToProps function should look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps, resolve) => {

    var myData;

    if (state.potentiallyLazy instanceof LazyLink) {
        resolve(state.potentiallyLazy);
    }
    else {
        myData = state.potentiallyLazy;
    }

    return {
        myData
    }
}
```

Any help how to achieve that, or a hint for a different approach? I had a look at connectAdvanced(), but didn't really find a solution with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the connect HOC to add your resolve function like

```
export connectAdvanced = (...args) => {
    const resolve = () => {} // your resolve function here
    const [mapStateToProps] = args;
    const overridenMapStateToProps  = (state, ownProps) => {
        mapStateToProps(state, ownProps, resolve)
    }  
    const restParams = [overridenMapStateToProps, ...args.slice(1)];
    return (Component) => connect.apply(null, restParms)(Component);
}
```

and use it like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps, resolve) => {

    var myData;

    if (state.potentiallyLazy instanceof LazyLink) {
        resolve(state.potentiallyLazy);
    }
    else {
        myData = state.potentiallyLazy;
    }

    return {
        myData
    }
}

export default connectAdvanced(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

However this approach no longer keeps your mapStateToProps function pure and you should consider moving the lazy loading action in the lifecycle methods, which is a better and correct way to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea on a couple levels.

First, your `mapState` functions *should* be pure, synchronous, and have no side effects, same as your reducers.

Second, it looks like you're keeping class instances in your store state, [which is discouraged because it will break time-travel debugging](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state).

If you need to trigger loading behavior, I would suggest putting it *inside* the component, in the lifecycle methods.